# visual studio publishes everything everytime

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using visual studio 2013 and mvc 5 project and I've encountered something really strange. when I publish the project using my home wifi, sometimes it publishes everything regardless of the updated files and not updated files and sometimes it publishes only the updated files (which is much faster). Then I go to office A and it always publishes the only updated files but when I go to office B it always publish everything. I've been using Visual studio 2012 and mvc4 before and I did not have any problem regarding publishing a project, only after I moved to VS 2013 it happened. Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds very weird, VS afaik publishes everything by default. Maybe there are some custom settings made to publish profile in your Office A? Can you provide more info on the topic, so we can maybe try to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: Yep, by default Visual Studio has no support to only publish updated files. It publishes everything, every time. Perhaps at Office A there's some third-party extension or something not present at the others that enables this functionality.

Comment: @walther I'm using ftp publish and the profile is the default except the address and username/password. other than that there rest is default. for example the scripts folder is Office A always takes a blink of eye to be published but right now at home it takes quiet some time.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I did not know that it doesn't support it. but from seeing those "not updated" files published so fast comparing the first publish of the project I assumed it does check for differences.

Comment: Since you're publishing via FTP, it's possible that it's actually checking the mtime of the file and only uploading it if it's different. Visual Studio still technically tries to publish everything, but not everything may actually be uploaded. However, if the mtime has changed, which can happen simply by copying the files to a new location, then it will be re-uploaded. That might be what's happening in your scenario.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Aha but the files location are not changed, just the code is changed but it's quiet strange the behavior it has. and since my project is quiet big it takes big time publishing the files :(